# bash script to add current date in each record as first column

Tags: bash

how to add the current date in a each record as first column.

**Input file:**

```
12345|Test1 
67890|Test2
```

**expected Output file:**

```
2014-04-26|12345|Test1 
2014-04-26|67890|Test2
```

Thanks,

Comment: do you have a script that you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use awk

```
awk -vOFS='|' -vcdate=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d') ' {print cdate, $0}' file
```

Comment: why set `-F` option ?

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e "s,^,$(date +'%Y-%M-%d')|," file
```

If you use Linux (more specifically, GNU sed) then you may use in-place editing with `-i` flag:

```
sed -i -e "s,^,$(date +'%Y-%M-%d')|," file
```

Otherwise you have to store results into a temporary file and then rename.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed for example:

```
sed -i  "/^$/ !s/^/`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`|/" data_file
```

Comment: @babyy The error you post is not produced by the code above, but by the gawk you use covertly. You can try to remove inner double quotes or replace them with single ones (since they are of no importance there) to see if it can be of any help. I actually wonder what gawk does in your stderr output.

Comment: @Babyy: my original answer was sed -i "s/^/\`date +'%y-%m-%d'\`|/" but it was edited by someone else. I suppose to manage empty lines, but the new command is wrong.

Comment: @Babyy you had multiple errors in your transcription. The script itself is fine. http://ideone.com/rxr5bk

Comment: (The clock on ideone.com seems to be off by several days, though.)

Comment: How to get the previous date instead of current date.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *edit* the file, why not use `ed`, the standard editor? the common and nice versions of `ed` will support the following:

```
printf '%s\n' "$(date '+%%s/^/%Y-%m-%d|/')" wq | ed -s file
```

(this will *edit* the file in place, so make sure you have appropriate backups if you want to revert the changes).

Comment: @eicto please tell me what my errors are (that would be a constructive comment!). Have you actually _tried_ it?

Comment: nope it is revenge for your nonconstructive comment :) calm down nothing evil. as myself I would to use `perl -pi -e`

Comment: @eicto revenge? non-constructive comment?